# ubuntu 20.04 touchscreen doesn't work on Lenovo ideapad flex 5

Tags: 20.04, lenovo, touchscreen, ideapad

I recently bought a Lenovo Flex 5 laptop, which has a touchscreen. I installed Ubuntu 20.04, and now I have it dual-booting Windows 10 (OEM) and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. On Windows the touchscreen works fine. On Ubuntu, everything else seems to work fine, however touchscreen does not work.
My graphic card is NVIDIA GeForce MX330. I am not sure if this relate to touchscreen or not.

I tried to to rebuild the kernel version 5.6.9, follow this page: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Ubuntu/Ideapad-5-15ARE05-Touchscreen-not-working/m-p/5017099?page=1, but failed when try to reboot from ubuntu 5.6.9.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that you're using a desktop environment that supports touch.

   a) **Unity Desktop**, latest **KDE** and **Gnome** are the best candidates to try.

   b) Please check your settings to see if Linux has detected the touch capability.

   c) Please also check if the setting to enable/use touch is turned on or off?
2. If you suspect that the drivers are missing you can try to install the **HWE kernel** for Ubuntu 20.04 which contains drivers for new hardware. (Warning - this may break your installation, proceed at your own risk!)

   Open a terminal and run the following command.

   `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04`

   Reboot your system after the installation is done.
3. You can try the edge version, a bit riskier than than the other above.

   `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04-edge`
4. Contact Lenovo and ask for a Linux driver. I've found Windows drivers on the Lenovo website, but no Linux driver :(
5. Wait, the drivers may arrive with a future kernel/linux-firmware.

You may also check if the touch input device is visible to the system using `xinput` in terminal. Should give you something like the following including the word **touch**.

```
~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ VirtualBox mouse integration              id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ VirtualBox USB Tablet                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse           id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

lshw and lsmod should also see it
`lshw |grep -i touch`
`lsmod |grep -i touch`

you should get someting like this

```
hid_multitouch         20480  0
```

You can also look for UNCLAIMED devices with no driver/module loaded.

`lshw |grep -i unclaimed`

If you find something promising you can pipe the output to `less` for further inspection.

`lshw |less`

**Sidenote**: the Ubutu [LTS Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) mentions the apt package `xserver-xorg-hwe-20.04`. I couldn't find this package using apt. It could be a typo on the wiki page or this package may be available later if needed.

Comment: Why do you think it is desktop issue? I think there are driver missing. Ubuntu comes with Gnome desktop, so it is sure doesn't work. I will try the other desktop. I am not optimistic about desktop will make different.

Comment: I agree, it won't work without the proper driver(s). I'm going to update my answer with a method to install latest available drivers.
To answer you question, some desktops support touch and some don't. 
I wanted to make sure that the desktop solution you are using does support touch, because you didn't mention your chosen desktop environment.

Comment: I am using default GNOME desktop. Touchpad and mouse works fine, only touch screen doesn't work. (I consider touch screen another type of mouse) 
I will try your new suggestion of HWE version. It is a new installation, so mess up will result in just another fresh installation, should be easy to recover if failed.

Comment: This doesn't work, the system shows I already have latest 20.04 installed, which make sense, because I just install the system a few days ago. I tried your command because I thought HWE is more advanced version than apt updata and upgrade.

 sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-20.04

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-generic-hwe-20.04 is already the newest version (5.4.0.58.61).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 293 not upgraded.

Comment: Added a way to install edge drivers and methods to test if the touch HW is visible to the system.

Comment: I ran sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04-edge, and got some errors, the system suggest to run apt-get update, so I did.
Then I re-ran sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04-edge, and installation of edge version successful.

Comment: I installed the edge version of ubuntu today by running: sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04-edge. The installation is successful, but after restarted, the touchscreen still doesn't work.

Comment: The output of running: 
~$ sudo lshw | more 
......
      *-serial:3 UNCLAIMED
             description: Serial bus controller
             product: Ice Lake-LP SPI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.5
             version: 30
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:4d400000-4d400fff
......

I think there is no solution right now, need to find if Lenovo provide any solution or not.